# I failed to steal from a NPC. I don't want to kill her because of a quest, but she keeps trying to kill me. What do I do?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I tried to steal from a girl in Kingdoms of Amalur. But she saw me or something like that and now she's trying to kill me if I approach her. The problem is that she's important in a quest I was doing. Is there a way to apologize for the steal to an NPC? Or will she forget with time?

Answer (score 5):

1.) **Reload.** If you're a chronic saver (or if you stole from her shortly after fast traveling or entering a building) just reload your latest save (or auto-save).

2.) **Run Away.** Just run away. After 2-3 game days, all will be forgiven.

3.) **Get caught.** Just not by her. If there are any NPC 'guard' characters nearby just turn yourself in. Pay the fine, pay the bribe or serve your time. Then all is well.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it takes about three days for hostile NPCs to forgive you for your actions. Try finding a bed and sleeping for a while, then come back; she will probably have forgiven you.

Comment: Hah man, someone implanted the idea in me that I would have been marked an outlaw forever until I was caught or killed by the now hostile NPCs. I assume that only those within that town will be hostile and not everyone with the same alignment in the game right?